# What is the weight of the Philae lander on the Churyumov–Gerasimenko comet compared to earth?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-gravity, mass, weight, comets

We know the [payload mass of the Philae lander was 21kg](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philae_(spacecraft)).

We know [the mass of the Churyumov–Gerasimenko comet is roughly 1 x 10^13kg](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/67P/Churyumov%E2%80%93Gerasimenko).

We know the [mass of Earth is roughly 5.9x10^24kg](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth_mass).

I've heard one estimate of the weight of the lander as 100 earth grams. Looking at the ratios  (1/(1 x 10^11)) that doesn't seem right to me.

My question is: **What is the weight of the Philae lander on the Churyumov–Gerasimenko comet compared to earth?** (And does it matter that the comet is Duck shaped? ie does the weight change depending on where on the comet it is?)

Comment: If you link to a source, please also copy the right values, Earth's is about $6.0\times 10^24\ kg$. Also note that the payload mass of Philae are the science instruments. The entire lander has a mass of about 100 kg.

Comment: $\uparrow$ should be $10^{24}$, not $10^24$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you rightly pointed out, the fact that 67P is oddly-shaped should alter its gravitational attraction on various parts of the comet.

That said, if we were to [go by Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/67P/Churyumov%E2%80%93Gerasimenko) in a rather off-hand manner, we find that the lander is $100 kg$ (as @fibonatic rightly pointed out) and 67P has an acceleration due to gravity of $\textbf{g'} = 10^{-3} m/s^2$. Its weight $W$ would therefore be simply a calculation of $W = m\,\textbf{g'}$, giving us $W = \frac{10^2}{10^3} kg = 0.1 kg$ or $100 \,\,\verb+earth+\, g$.

<s>[P.S. I will update this answer with better sources than Wikipedia as soon as I find time.]</s>

**Edit 1:** [This ESA webpage](http://blogs.esa.int/rosetta/2014/10/03/measuring-comet-67pc-g/) seems to confirm the figures.

**Edit 2:** ***Calculating*** $\textbf{g'}$

I made some calculations:
Using the formula $\textbf{F} = M\,\textbf{g'} = \frac{GmM}{r^2} \Rightarrow \textbf{g'} = \frac{GM}{r^2}$ we can calculate the acceleration due to gravity on 67P (m being the comet's mass and M that of our lander). The above ESA page gives us this figure:

[image: ESA]

Seeing how the dimensions vary wildly, I decided to consider a mean of, say, 3.5km as diameter and 1.75km as $r$. 67P's mass is, of course, $10^{13}\,kg$ which gives us,
$$
\textbf{g'} = \frac{6.67 \times 10^{-11} \times 10^{13}}{\left( 1.75 \times 10^3 \right)^2} \approx 10^{-3} ms^{-2}
$$
A more precise answer, is, of course, $0.217 \times 10^{-3} ms^{-2}$ but since we have been very liberal in our assumptions of mass and radius, I think we ought to simply consider the order of magnitude, $10^{-3} ms^{-2}$. [This pdf file](http://www.simpack.com/fileadmin/simpack/doc/usermeeting04/um04_maxplanck_hilch.pdf) contains some simulation data that agrees with our result.

Comment: The actual weight of Philae at the landing site is said to be about [1 gram](http://www.spacenews.com/article/civil-space/42527european-spacecraft-touches-down-on-comet), not your mentioned 0.1 kg or 100 gram. This is due to your rounding and not considering the centripetal acceleration due to the rotating reference frame of the comet.

Comment: @fibonatic Good point.That makes me wonder where the OP got his 100g figure. He doesn't link to a source. Perhaps the calculations were simplified like mine and made prior to our obtaining reliable data about 67P.

Comment: it also seems that you are taking the mean of the diameter and not the radius, which would also reduce your estimated surface gravity by a factor 4, which when rounded would end up an order of magnitude lower than your current one. And I am not sure how reliable that PDF is, since it say that it is from 2004, the year Rosetta jut launched.

Comment: @fibonatic Thanks, I'll update the answer with corrections. But I don't see how the order of magnitude changes.

Answer (score 2):

The appeared weight of an object does not only depend on the mass of the celestial body by which it is attracted. If you simplify to spherical symmetry, which is not definitely not that case for the comet 67P (in to a lesser extend also not for the Earth) you can approximate the ratios of weight by using [Newton's law of universal gravitation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton's_law_of_universal_gravitation):

$$
g=\frac{GM}{R^2},
$$
where $g$ is the acceleration due to gravity at the surface, $G$ is the gravitational constant, $M$ and $R$ are the mass and (mean) radius of the celestial body.

Depending on where you are on 67P you might also want to include the centripetal acceleration, which can be neglected for on Earth, since its much smaller relative to its gravity. If the radius of the landing site is roughly at the equator (the vector between the landing site and center of mass close to perpendicular to the direction of the rotation of the comet) then then following equation can be used for the surface acceleration (as seen from the rotating reference frame of the comet):

$$
a=\frac{GM}{R^2}-\omega^2R,
$$
where $\omega$ is the angular velocity with which the body rotates.

The intended [landing site J](http://www.esa.int/Our_Activities/Space_Science/Rosetta/J_marks_the_spot_for_Rosetta_s_lander) of Philae (it eventually landed about one kilometer away) is about 2.8 km away from the center of 67P (for this I combined this [scale image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5oMpB.png) and this [video](http://www.theregister.co.uk/2014/08/21/rosetta_spacecraft_makes_first_measurement_of_comet_67ps_mass/) showing its center) and the angular velocity can be derived from the rotational period of [12.4 hours](http://sci.esa.int/rosetta/14615-comet-67p/). Combining this yields an approximated acceleration at the surface of the landing site of:
$$
a_J=3.0 \times 10^{-5}\ ms^{-2}.
$$
This is approximately a factor $3\times 10^{-6}$ times smaller than the surface gravity on Earth (which is approximately $9.8\ ms^{-2}$). So according to these estimations the 100 kilogram lander would at the landing site weigh about 0.3 grams, which is quite close the to mentioned 1 gram in [this article](http://www.spacenews.com/article/civil-space/42527european-spacecraft-touches-down-on-comet). The error most likely for the most part comes from the assumption that the comet is spherical.

Comment: Wow, the rotation reduces the apparent surface gravity by 65%! Since the result is a delicate near-cancellation of two numbers, it's not surprising that the non-spherical shape would severely limit the precision of the result. The landing site may also not be near the equator.

Comment: @BenCrowell the video and the image of the landing site I linked to do seem to suggest that it is near the equator. I think its strange shape also might suggest that it might be two comets collided together, hence the two lobes with narrow neck and relatively high rotational velocity.

Comment: That was my first thought as well. Do we have any explanations on the shape?

Comment: @V.H.Belvadi [this article](http://www.theguardian.com/science/2014/jul/20/comet-67p-rosetta-probe-close-encounter-origins-of-life-churyumov-gerasimenko) does mention two different possible explanations, quoted from mission scientist Matt Taylor. Namely collision of two objects (contact binary) or it was initially a more round object, but the close passes near the sun removed volatile material. The second hypothesis will be tested during the upcoming close encounter.